# MVC 4 Routing: multiple match error due to api\controller\action\id and api\controller\id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to set up a routing configuration and am having the exception "Multiple actions were found that match the request: "

The error appears when I go to /api/Devices/{id}

I know the culprit method - GetParts. Why is it still triggering as a possible match for controller/id? How do I get it to stop, or ONLY the get method to apply?

```
    public Devices Get(int id)
    {
        return Uow.Distribution.Devices.GetById(id);
    }

    [ActionName("GetParts")]
    public IEnumerable<DeviceParts> GetParts(int id)
    {
        return Uow.Distribution.Devices.GetParts(id);
    }
```

My Routes

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerOnly,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
            );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAndId,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAction,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerActionAndId,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
        );
```

Thanks